# Ping multiple device names (hostname) on the Network

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, ping

A DataGridView displays hostnames at Column index `0`, computer / printer names on the network.

```
pc1
pc2
print3
pc5
print
....
```

There are more than 500 such names.
I know how to ping them:

```
For i = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
    Try
        If My.Computer.Network.Ping(DataGridView1.Item(0, i).Value) = True Then
            DataGridView1.Rows(i).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Lime
        Else
            DataGridView1.Rows(i).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        DataGridView1.Rows(i).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red
    End Try
Next
```

The problem is that the Ping takes a very long time and the application freezes.
How can you speed up this procedure?
And let's say if the node is not available, then simply remove it from the list.

Comment: How about https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.ping.sendasync?view=netframework-4.8 ?

Comment: Thanks, can I have an example for my case?

Answer (score 2):

An example to Ping multiple addresses at the same time, using the async version of provided by the [Ping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.ping) class, [Ping.SendPingAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.ping.sendpingasync).
This version is await-able, not the same as the [Ping.SendAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.ping.sendasync) method, still *asynchronous* but event-driven.

Since you're using a DataGridView to both store the IpAddress/HostName and to present the `PingReply` results, you need to determine a way to match the Ping result to correct Cell of the DataGridView from which the Ip/Host address was taken.
Here, I'm passing to the method the Row's Index, so when the Ping result comes back, asynchronously, we can match the response to a specific Cell in the DataGridView.

To make the *initialization* method more generic, I'm passing also the index of the Column where the Ip/Host address is stored and the index of the Column that will show the result (you could also just pass all indexes, not a DataGridView Control reference to the method and handle the results in a different way).

A loop extracts the addresses from the the DataGridView and creates a **`List(Of Task)`**, adding a `PingAsync()` Task for each address found.
When the collection is completed, the `List(Of Task)` is passed to the [Task.WhenAll()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall) method, which is then awaited.
This method starts all the Task in the list and returns when all Task have a result.

► Note that the Ping procedure sets a `TimeOut`, to `5000ms` here, so all the Tasks will return before or within that interval, successful or not.
You can then decide if you want to reschedule the failed Pings or not.

The UI update is handled using a [Progress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.progress-1) delegate. It's just a method (Action delegate) that is called when the Ping procedure has a result to show.
It can also be used when the method that updates the UI runs in a different Thread: the [Report()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iprogress-1.report) method will call the Progress object delegate in the Thread that created the delegate: the UI Thread, here (in the example, we're not actually ever leaving it, though).

This is how it works:

[image: Mass Ping with DataGridView]

---

Assume you're starting the ping sequence from  `Button.Click` event handler.
Note that the handler is declared `async`.

```
Private Async Sub btnMassPing_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnMassPing.Click
    Await MassPing(DataGridView1, 1, 2)
End Sub
```

Initialization method and `IProgress<T>` report handler:

```
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Net.NetworkInformation
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Threading.Tasks

Private Async Function MassPing(dgv As DataGridView, statusColumn As Integer, addressColumn As Integer) As Task
    Dim obj = New Object()
    Dim tasks = New List(Of Task)()

    Dim progress = New Progress(Of (sequence As Integer, reply As Object))(
            Sub(report)
                SyncLock obj
                    Dim status = IPStatus.Unknown
                    If TypeOf report.reply Is PingReply Then
                        status = DirectCast(report.reply, PingReply).Status
                    ElseIf TypeOf report.reply Is SocketError Then
                        Dim socErr = DirectCast(report.reply, SocketError)
                        status = If(socErr = SocketError.HostNotFound,
                            IPStatus.DestinationHostUnreachable,
                            IPStatus.Unknown)
                    End If

                    Dim color As Color = If(status = IPStatus.Success, Color.Green, Color.Red)
                    Dim cell = dgv(statusColumn, report.sequence)
                    cell.Style.BackColor = color
                    cell.Value = If(status = IPStatus.Success, "Online", status.ToString())
                End SyncLock
            End Sub)

    For row As Integer = 0 To dgv.Rows.Count - 1
        If row = dgv.NewRowIndex Then Continue For
        Dim ipAddr = dgv(addressColumn, row).Value.ToString()
        tasks.Add(PingAsync(ipAddr, 5000, row, progress))
    Next

    Try
        Await Task.WhenAll(tasks)
    Catch ex As Exception
        ' Log / report the exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Function
```

`PingAsync` worker method:

```
Private Async Function PingAsync(ipAddress As String, timeOut As Integer, sequence As Integer, progress As IProgress(Of (seq As Integer, reply As Object))) As Task
    Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(32) {}
    Dim ping = New Ping()

    Try
        Dim options = New PingOptions(64, True)
        Dim reply = Await ping.SendPingAsync(ipAddress, timeOut, buffer, options)
        progress.Report((sequence, reply))
    Catch pex As PingException
        If TypeOf pex.InnerException Is SocketException Then
            Dim socEx = DirectCast(pex.InnerException, SocketException)
            progress.Report((sequence, socEx.SocketErrorCode))
        End If
    Finally
        ping.Dispose()
    End Try
End Function
```