# Ping the network quickly

Tags: vb.net, winforms, ping

good day!
Tell me how you can quickly ping the entire network?
There is the following code that scans the network.

```vb
  Public Sub Scan(ByVal subnet As String)
        Dim myPing As Ping
        Dim reply As PingReply
        Dim addr As IPAddress
        Dim host As IPHostEntry
        Dim active_addr As Integer = 0

        ProgressBar1.Maximum = 254
        ProgressBar1.Value = 0
        ListView1.Items.Clear()

        For i As Integer = 1 To 254

            Dim subnetn As String = "." & i.ToString()
            myPing = New Ping()

            reply = myPing.Send(subnet & subnetn, 900)

            Label3.ForeColor = Color.Green
            Label3.Text = "Scan: " & subnet & subnetn

            If reply.Status = IPStatus.Success Then
                Try
                    addr = IPAddress.Parse(subnet & subnetn)
                    host = Dns.GetHostEntry(addr)


                    If My.Computer.Network.Ping(host.HostName, 10) Then
                        ListView1.Items.Add(New ListViewItem(New String() {subnet & subnetn, host.HostName, "True"}))
                    Else
                        ListView1.Items.Add(New ListViewItem(New String() {subnet & subnetn, host.HostName, "False"}))
                    End If
                Catch
                    ListView1.Items.Add(New ListViewItem(New String() {subnet & subnetn, " ", "False"}))
                End Try
                active_addr += 1

            End If
            ProgressBar1.Value += 1
            Label5.Text = Math.Round((ProgressBar1.Value * 100) / 254, 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) & " %"
            ')

            ListView1.Items((ListView1.Items.Count - 1)).EnsureVisible()
            ListView1.Items((ListView1.Items.Count - 1)).Selected = True

        Next i


        ListView1.Items(0).Focused = True
        ListView1.Items(0).Selected = True
    End Sub
```

But it takes a very long time to scan the network. Tell me, is it possible to do it faster?
And can I add the device's MAC address when scanning the network?

================================================================

Found a solution that quickly scans the network (a given range of ip addresses).

Tell me. how to add to this code to display the hostname and the MAC address? and add a ProgressBar to show the scan percentage.

```vb
   Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Ping("192.168.1.28", "175")
    End Sub
    Private Async Function Ping(startIP As String, endIP As String) As Task
        Dim start As IPAddress = IPAddress.Parse(startIP)
        Dim bytes = start.GetAddressBytes()
        Dim leastSigByte = start.GetAddressBytes().Last
        Dim range = endIP - leastSigByte

        Dim pingReplyTasks = Enumerable.Range(leastSigByte, range).Select(Function(x)
                                                                              Dim p = New Ping()
                                                                              Dim bb = start.GetAddressBytes()
                                                                              bb(3) = CByte(x)
                                                                              Dim destIp = New IPAddress(bb)
                                                                              Dim pingResultTask = p.SendPingAsync(destIp)
                                                                              Return New With {
        Key pingResultTask,
        Key .addr = destIp
    }
                                                                          End Function).ToList()

        Await Task.WhenAll(pingReplyTasks.Select(Function(x) x.pingResultTask))

        For Each pr In pingReplyTasks
            Dim tsk = pr.pingResultTask
            Dim pingResult = tsk.Result
            Dim ip = pr.addr
            '


            DataGridView1.Rows.Add(ip, pingResult.RoundtripTime, pingResult.Status)

        Next pr

    End Function
```

Comment: You could run some concurrent Tasks, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66013390/7444103). It uses the async version, `SendPingAsync()`.

Comment: thanks for the hint. did everything as described in this post. but how to add another mac address and hostname there?