# If statement not moving to the next item

Tags: vb.net

I am working on a side project in VB, it is a network monitoring tool to pings a number of devices which should come back as successful or failed. I have extreme limits in programming so forgive me.

I am using buttons, a total of 34 for each device that I want to ping that returns a success or fail which will color code green(success) and red(failed) but I am sure there is a better way? Right now, my code is stuck on one button, I cant figure out how to step to the next one on the list. In my code, I have it commented out of the results I want produced which is where I am stuck on.

The text file contains all my IP addresses I want to ping separated by a comma.

Basically, when the form is running, it will display each button as green or red, depending on if the device is online or not. I want the code to loop every 2 minutes as well to keep the devices up to date. Literally a device monitoring tool. I was able to get it to work using 34 different End If statements but that is messy and a lot of work to maintain. Any assistance would be helpful.

```
Using MyReader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser("\\txt file location\device.txt")
    MyReader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
    MyReader.SetDelimiters(",")
    Dim currentRow As String()
    Dim MyLen() As String = {"Button1", "Button2", "Button3", "Button4", "Button5", "Button6", "Button7", "Button8", "Button9", "Button10", "Button11", "Button12", "Button13", "Button14", "Button15", "Button16", "Button17", "Button18", "Button19", "Button20", "Button21", "Button22", "Button23", "Button24", "Button25", "Button26", "Button27", "Button28", "Button29", "Button30", "Button31", "Button32", "Button33", "Button34"}
    While Not MyReader.EndOfData
        Try
            currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields()
            Dim currentField As String
            For Each currentField In currentRow
                If My.Computer.Network.Ping(currentField) Then
                    MsgBox(MyLen)
                    'MyLen = Color.LimeGreen
                Else
                    MsgBox(MyLen)
                    'MyLen.Text = "Failed"
                    'MyLen.BackColor = Color.Red

                End If

            Next
        Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException
            MsgBox("Line " & ex.Message & "is not valid and will be skipped.")
        End Try
    End While
End Using
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byDkl.png)

Comment: `Dim MyButtons = {Button1, Button2, ...)` - Increment a counter in the loop and use it as the indexer of `MyButtons` (e.g., `MyButtons([Counter]).Text = "Some text"` etc.) -- You should pre-load the IP Addresses, store the array of Buttons and use a Timer update the UI.

Comment: I'd suggest to call the [SendPingAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.ping.sendpingasync) method of `System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping` class instead of that thing you're using now. To run and await concurrently. -- E.g., see the `MassPing()` method here: [Ping multiple device names (hostname) on the Network](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66013390/7444103), which updates a DataGridView with the results

Comment: Thank you Jimi, I got it to work! I have one more question. I want the form to open up and continue to run. Right now, I have a counter set up with a sleep timer of 1 second. The form opens up after it completes the count, but i want the count to continue after it opens. Do I need to create a new sub over top of my current one?

Comment: I don't know what code you have now or if you took the sample code I've posted before. Anyways, when you have stored a list of IP Addresses to ping, just repeat the Ping procedure using a Timer. In the Timer handler, you 1)  suspend the Timer 2) `await` (as shown the example, or wait, but that's bad since it freezes the UI) for the method that performs the Ping sequence to return 3) resume the Timer. -- A Tick / Delay of 1 second is way too low and pretty much useless. 5 seconds is the minimum. If you're pinging Internet Servers, note that your Address could be black-listed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that takes a different approach.  To try it create a new Form app with only a FlowLayoutPanel and Timer on it.  Use the default names. It might be above your skill level but using the debugger you might learn something.  Or not.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private MyButtons As New List(Of Button)

    Private Sub Form1_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
        Timer1.Enabled = False 'started later
        Timer1.Interval = CInt(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2).TotalMilliseconds) '<<<< Change >>>>

        Dim path As String = "\\txt file location\device.txt"
        Dim text As String = IO.File.ReadAllText(path) 'use this

        ''for testing >>>>>
        'Dim text As String = "10.88.0.70,  10.88.0.122,192.168.0.15, 10.88.0.254, 1.2.3.4" ''for testing
        ''for testing <<<<<

        Dim spltCHs() As Char = {","c, " "c, ControlChars.Tab, ControlChars.Cr, ControlChars.Lf}
        Dim IPs() As String = text.Split(spltCHs, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

        For Each addr As String In IPs
            Dim b As New Button
            Dim p As New MyPinger(addr)
            p.MyButton = b
            b.Tag = p 'set tag to the MyPinger for this address

            b.AutoSize = True
            b.Font = New Font("Lucida Console", 10, FontStyle.Bold)
            b.BackColor = Drawing.Color.LightSkyBlue

            'center text in button
            Dim lAddr As String = p.Address
            Dim t As String = New String(" "c, (16 - lAddr.Length) \ 2)
            Dim txt As String = t & lAddr & t
            b.Text = txt.PadRight(16, " "c)
            b.Name = "btn" & lAddr.Replace("."c, "_"c)

            AddHandler b.Click, AddressOf SomeButton_Click 'handler for button
            MyButtons.Add(b) 'add button to list
        Next

        'sort by IP
        MyButtons = (From b In MyButtons
                     Select b Order By DirectCast(b.Tag, MyPinger).Address(True)).ToList

        For Each b As Button In MyButtons
            FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(b) 'add button to panel
        Next

        FlowLayoutPanel1.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom Or AnchorStyles.Left Or AnchorStyles.Right Or AnchorStyles.Top
        Timer1.Enabled = True 'start the timer
    End Sub

    Private Sub SomeButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        'if button clicked ping it
        Dim b As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button) 'which button
        b.BackColor = MyPinger.UnknownColor
        Dim myP As MyPinger = DirectCast(b.Tag, MyPinger) ''get the MyPinger for this
        myP.DoPing() 'do the ping
    End Sub

    Private Async Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Timer1.Enabled = False
        Dim myPs As New List(Of MyPinger)
        For Each b As Button In MyButtons
            b.BackColor = MyPinger.UnknownColor
            Dim myP As MyPinger = DirectCast(b.Tag, MyPinger)
            myPs.Add(myP)
        Next

        Dim t As Task
        t = Task.Run(Sub()
                         Threading.Thread.Sleep(25)
                         For Each myP As MyPinger In myPs
                             myP.DoPing()
                         Next
                     End Sub)

        Await t
        Timer1.Enabled = True
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class MyPinger
    Public Shared ReadOnly UpColor As Drawing.Color = Drawing.Color.LightGreen
    Public Shared ReadOnly DownColor As Drawing.Color = Drawing.Color.Red
    Public Shared ReadOnly UnknownColor As Drawing.Color = Drawing.Color.Yellow

    Private _ip As Net.IPAddress
    Private _ping As Net.NetworkInformation.Ping
    Public LastReply As Net.NetworkInformation.PingReply
    Private Shared ReadOnly PingTMO As Integer = 2500
    Private _waiter As New Threading.AutoResetEvent(True)
    Public MyButton As Button

    Public Sub New(IPAddr As String)
        Me._ip = Net.IPAddress.Parse(IPAddr) 'will throw exception if IP invalid <<<<<
        Me._ping = New Net.NetworkInformation.Ping 'create the ping
        'do initial ping
        Dim t As Task = Task.Run(Sub()
                                     Threading.Thread.Sleep(25) 'so init has time
                                     Me.DoPingAsync()
                                 End Sub)
    End Sub

    Private Async Sub DoPingAsync()
        If Me._waiter.WaitOne(0) Then 'only one at a time for this IP
            Me.LastReply = Await Me._ping.SendPingAsync(Me._ip, PingTMO)
            Dim c As Drawing.Color
            Select Case Me.LastReply.Status
                Case Net.NetworkInformation.IPStatus.Success
                    c = UpColor
                Case Else
                    c = DownColor
            End Select
            Me.SetButColor(c)
            Me._waiter.Set()
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub DoPing()
        Me.DoPingAsync()
    End Sub

    Private Sub SetButColor(c As Drawing.Color)
        If Me.MyButton IsNot Nothing Then
            If Me.MyButton.InvokeRequired Then
                Me.MyButton.BeginInvoke(Sub()
                                            Me.SetButColor(c)
                                        End Sub)
            Else
                Me.MyButton.BackColor = c
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Function TheIP() As Net.IPAddress
        Return Me._ip
    End Function

    Public Function Address(Optional LeadingZeros As Boolean = False) As String
        Dim rv As String = ""
        If LeadingZeros Then
            Dim byts() As Byte = Me._ip.GetAddressBytes
            For Each b As Byte In byts
                rv &= b.ToString.PadLeft(3, "0"c)
                rv &= "."
            Next
        Else
            rv = Me._ip.ToString
        End If
        Return rv.Trim("."c)
    End Function
End Class
```