# How to Get IP Addresses in LAN Network Using VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, networking, ip, ip-address

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8RN2.png)I want to get IP addresses in That are connected with LAN network. I seen a youtube tutorial [Youtube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=65LJH-ctLvM&t=533s)  Got the addresses but only last address show here in my dataGridView
I want to get all addresses in datagridviewlist using VB.Net

Maybe my english is bit lower but I need help

## This is My Code

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.NetworkInformation
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim strHost As String
        Dim strIp As String
        strHost = Dns.GetHostName()
        strIp = Dns.GetHostByName(strHost).AddressList(0).ToString()
        TxtForIp.Text = strIp
    End Sub

    Private Sub BgScanningForIps_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BgScanningForIps.DoWork
        Dim ping As Ping
        Dim addr As IPAddress
        Dim pinRpl As PingReply
        Dim host As IPHostEntry
        Dim name As String

        Thread.Sleep(500)

        Parallel.For(0, 254, Sub(i, loopState)
                                 ping = New Ping()
                                 pinRpl = ping.Send(TxtForIp.Text + i.ToString())
                                 Me.BeginInvoke(CType(Sub()
                                                          If pinRpl.Status = IPStatus.Success Then
                                                              Try
                                                                  addr = IPAddress.Parse(TxtForIp.Text + i.ToString())
                                                                  host = Dns.GetHostEntry(addr)
                                                                  name = host.HostName
                                                                  DataGridView1.Rows.Add()
                                                                  Dim nRowIndex As Integer = DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
                                                                  DataGridView1.Rows(nRowIndex).Cells(0).Value = TxtForIp.Text + i.ToString()
                                                                  DataGridView1.Rows(nRowIndex).Cells(1).Value = name
                                                                  DataGridView1.Rows(nRowIndex).Cells(2).Value = "active"
                                                              Catch ex As Exception
                                                                  name = "?"
                                                              End Try
                                                          End If
                                                      End Sub, Action))
                             End Sub)

        MessageBox.Show("Scanned")

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        BgScanningForIps.RunWorkerAsync()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Please give the answer with complete code I am new and face a problem with a specific small code.

Comment: Have you tried without the `Parallel.For`?  You don't have any protection for the max index, so there's a risk of multiple iterations all trying to stuff their results into the same row.

Comment: without `Parallel.For`   What will the code be?

Comment: [Ping multiple device names (hostname) on the Network](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66013390/7444103)

Comment: At Least I Got the Lan IPs in the Listbox now my goal is to connect to MySQL dynamically from one of the gotten IPs